# Google Sheets Query And Importrange Equals Cell D2

Tags: google-sheets

I've got two spreadsheets, a primary sheet (that a google form dumps into) and another sheet (aka management sheet) that has shared access to the primary sheet.  I'm trying to run the query below to automatically import a serial number based on the hostname in column D of the management sheet.

I can run a simple importrange successfully, so the access permissions are working properly.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[URLHERE]”, “Form Responses 1!A2:H”), ”Select Col7 where Col5="&$D2))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Jerome

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SINGLE(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1pRWLfnYsJhmJFZio_pvny7oO8UCSUxfGhTc78TbwVhw", 
 "Form Responses 1!A:H")}, "select Col7 where Col5 = '"&D2&"'", )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
=query({IMPORTRANGE("1pRWLfnYsJhmJFZio_pvny7oO8UCSUxfGhTc78TbwVhw", "Form Responses 1!A2:H")}, "Select Col7 where Col5 = '"&D2&"' LIMIT 1",0)
```

Jerome